# Conversion failed when converting varchar value '{}' to data type int?

Tags: python, sql

I'm very new to SQL, so I'm just getting my bearings with it. I want to delete a row based on an int value, DataID, passed in by some other method. Here is the code:

```
query = ("""DELETE FROM TradeSupportPortal.dbo.ExchangeDropCopyIgnore
                    WHERE TradeSupportPortal..ExchangeDropCopyIgnore.DropCopyID = '{}'""")

query.format(dataID)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.__connection_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
cnxn.commit()
```

However, I get an error message saying "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{}' to data type int." I'm not sure why, because dataID is an int. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strings are immutable so calling `.format` on it doesn't *change* it -- It creates a new string.

You probably wanted to do:

```
query = query.format(dataId)
```

to store the *new* string that got formatted.  With that said, **there is a better way**.  You should use your database connector's  [paramstyle](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) -- It *usually* looks something like this:

```
query = """DELETE FROM TradeSupportPortal.dbo.ExchangeDropCopyIgnore
                   WHERE TradeSupportPortal..ExchangeDropCopyIgnore.DropCopyID = '%s'"""

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.__connection_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, dataID)
cnxn.commit()
```

Formatting the string yourself leaves you open to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks.